# Why does adding the xmlns attribute to a component change the DOM?

Tags: html, jsf, oracle-adf

I was trying to create  a page and ran into an issue where a div was being rendered inside of it's sibling. After a while of debugging I noticed that i had the xmlns attribute on a table and removed it on a whim and noticed that that had fixed my issue.

This was done with JDeveloper deployed to the Integrated Weblogic Server. The divs could be html, jsf or adf components and the behavior is the same. When I discovered this the component with xmlns was a html table

Whenever I would have something similar to this

```
<div id="ExampleParent1">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div id="ExampleChild1">ExampleText1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ExampleParent2">
        <div id="ExampleChild2">ExampleText2</div>
</div>
```

It would be rendered like this

```
<div id="ExampleParent1">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div id="ExampleChild1">ExampleText1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="ExampleParent2">
        <div id="ExampleChild2">ExampleText2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why would having the xmlns attribute cause this?

Comment: @Selaron thank you! I couldn't find an answer guess you're better at searching than I am :)

Comment: It was just 'by accident' because I knew having seen and/or answered a question of that kind shortly ;)

Comment: What is remarkable is that I've never seen this happening/asked in many years and now twice in a month. What is your JSF version? Maybe it is a regression in a recent release

Comment: @Kukeltje It looks like I'm using 2.2.8-21. I'm pretty new to JSF so maybe it's just me not being very good.

Comment: Reproduced using Mojarra 2.3.3, 2.3.8, 2.4.0 and now reported as issue [#4555](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4555)

Comment: No Matthew, no related, don't worry ;-) @Selaron: thanks, I've seen BalusC commenting that it thisas an issue before and got fixed back then... maybe you can even find that issue and reference it (sorry, see you did)

Comment: @Kukeltje I referred to the similar issue [#2972](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/2972) - did you mean that or another one?

Comment: ;-) I was lazy and only read your issue after commenting... **SORRY**